# Extract an image of a corrupted Android partition bit-to-bit

Tags: data-recovery, partitions

How can I extract an image of the corrupted Android partition `mmcblk0` bit-to-bit?
With `adb pull`, it says remote I/O error after a few megabytes.

Comment: May be an Android version of `ddrescue` could help to bypass the nonreadable sections. You should be able to pipe out the copied data via `adb exec-out`.

Comment: exactly. ask [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/native-arm-linux-binaries-for-android-encfs-cryptsetup-photorec-smbnetfs.3709380) someone will compile. or try [dd_rescue_ARMv5_API9.zip](https://www.mediafire.com/file/dr2zmmg1mbsabeq) (it's old but should work)

Comment: @alecxs As far as I remember those old binaries won't work on Android 4+ because of missing PIE/ASLR feature in binary.